# Create Socket with AF_UNSPEC argument

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

Does the socket creation fail if the first argument is AF_UNSPEC for socket() UNIX API or if it does work what will it be defaulted to?

Comment: Why not simply try? A small test program shows: `socket(AF_UNSPEC,SOCK_STREAM,6) -> EAFNOSUPPORT`

Comment: Are you asking about this because you want a socket that works for both IPv4 and IPv6 communications?  If so, you might want to check out setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, ...), as that can be used to make an AF_INET6 socket also able to communicate via IPv4.

Comment: But in this case please note that setting IPV6_V6ONLY to 0 (i.e. handle both IPv4 and IPv6 on the same socket) is not supported in all systems, notably not in OpenBSD.